# If $\sum_j \frac 1 j a_j $ is summable where $\{a_k\}$ is a positive sequence, then is $\liminf a_k = 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\sum_{j} \frac 1 j a_j < \infty$ and $a_j$ is a positive sequence, is it that $\liminf_{k \to \infty} a_k = 0$?

If not, suppose $\liminf a_k = 2\varepsilon > 0$,  for sufficiently large $k$, we have $a_k \ge 2\varepsilon - \varepsilon = \varepsilon$. This leads to that $\sum_j \frac{1} {j} a_j $ is not summable. Is this argument correct?

Comment: I like your argument.

Comment: Consider $a_k,a_{2k}$ perhaps ??

Comment: If I were your professor, I would want a paragraph giving the details of "this leads to ..."

Comment: @Shalop What about the example: $a_n = \begin{cases} 1, & n = 2^k \mathrm{~for~some~}k \in \mathbb{N} \\ \frac{1}{n}, & \mathrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$ ?  It seems to me that there, $\sum_j \frac{1}{j} a_j < \infty$ and therefore $\liminf a_k = 0$, but $\limsup a_k = 1$.  (The linked question assumes $a_k$ is nonincreasing, which we're not assuming here.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yep, I assumed $a_k$ was nondecreasing. So my previous comment (now deleted) is wrong, sorry!

Comment: Your argument is perfectly fine. Maybe justify the little details if this is on a homework.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Yes it's correct although my preference is to say " for $all$ sufficiently large $k$" or " for or all but finitely many $k$" instead of "for sufficiently large $k$"

Comment: @DanielSchepler . I have been criticized for saying "$f$ is non-increasing" because  that could be interpreted as "$f$ is not an increasing function" . A common modern style is that "$f$ is increasing" means $x>y\implies f(x)\geq f(y)$ and that "$f$ is strictly increasing" means $x>y\implies f(x)>f(y).$  Similarly for "decreasing"

Comment: @Shalop . See my comment above to DanielSchepler.